# Asp.Net Content Donwload very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to understand how to remove a bottleneck in our asp.net application
Version of .net is 4.7.2.

Here is an async request from our service with approx 300kb of content:

[Google chrome timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFFLI.png)

I have the same time from both ashx handler or MVC controller. I tried to enable compression but the download time is proportional to the content size. In debug mode locally in IIS express, the download content is done immediately.
It seems that there is an open buffer that limits the data output.
Is there a workaround to send data immediately without this download delay?

For production server, we are using Cloud Services in Azure.

Comment: You can check IIS to make sure IIS doesn't limit the speed by following this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/limits). Make sure maximum bandwidth is 4294967295. Then tell your server's antivirus to ignore compressed files in web directory.

Comment: Hi, IIS limits were not changed and i have seen that they are correct, with the max bandwidth available. I have already tride also BufferOutput = false in response object

Comment: IIS and asp.net do not limit the download speed, I think you can check the Azure cloud service, or switch the network to test the download speed.